# Why is it returning a negative value for a very long binary string?

Tags: java

```
public long bin_to_dec() {
    int leng = a.length();

    for (int i = 0, j = (leng - 1); i < leng; i++, j--) {

        int number = Character.getNumericValue(a.charAt(j));
        result = result + (number * ((long) Math.pow(2, i)));

    }
    return result;
}
```

This code takes a binary string as argument and return it's decimal value .
but for a long string i.e.

```
(111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111)
```

it returns -28 .
Why is the memory out of range?
or is my code is incorrect?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Comment: "This code takes a binary string as argument" - Are you sure? It looks niladic to me.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably overrunning the length of an int. Integers in java are 32 bit and that binary string is 91 bits.

Try using something like `BigInteger` instead, which will not overflow. In fact, `BigInteger` has a built-in method for this:

```
BigInteger result = new BigInteger(a, 2);
```

Comment: The question uses a `long` which takes 64 bits. Either way, it won't work, though.

Comment: Point taken, I was reading too fast and didn't see the `result` declared and missed the return type. Still 91 > 64. ;)

Comment: So i have to restrict my string to 64 bits only?

Comment: If you want to use a long, you have to restrict it to 63 (the 64th leftmost bit being the sign bit). Otherwise, use BigInteger and you can have an arbitrary length (of course, your `long` return type won't work then).

Comment: And now that I look at it, your code as written doesn't handle negative numbers (it would fail on `-3` because `getNumericValue` would fail for `-`).